# Filtro CLOB - Numero+texto

Tags: oracle, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho um sistema cujo todos os campos de um documento são CLOBs, inclusive combo box com míseros "Sim" e "Não".
Estou construindo uma query, preciso filtrar um campo Clob e os valores são '0||Sim' e '1||Não'.

Eis o que já fiz:

> Having campoclob like '0||Sim' Erro:ORA-22835: Buffer muito pequeno
>   para conversão  de Clob em Char ou de BLOB em RAW
>   (real:4300,Máximo:4.000)
>
> CASE campoclob like '0||Sim' THEN 0 else 1 END Erro:ORA-22835: Buffer
>   muito pequeno para conversão  de Clob em Char ou de BLOB em RAW
>   (real:4300,Máximo:4.000)

Enfim, tudo o que eu mudo dá o mesmo erro, são 325 resultados que sem filtro mostra o campo com os valores corretos, até usando o case, mas não consigo filtrar que dá o erro. Analisei todos os documentos e não há problema com os campos, como são combobox não tem como o usuário digitar, nos outros meses a query roda sem problemas.

Comment: Ana, seria possível passar o restante da consulta ou montar um simples exemplo no SQLFiddle? CLOB com agrupamentos sempre é uma dor de cabeça ...

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho como testar agora, mas tenta assim:

```
Having dbms_lob.substr( campoclob, 4000, 1 ) like '0||Sim'
```

Comment: Também já havia tentado com esta função, joguei lá novamente e da o mesmo erro. o problema é no WHERE, quando jogo no where valor=1 ele da o erro de clob

Comment: tenta trim(valor) = '1'